# jQuery Accordion nav issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

So finally, I was able to create a simple accordion nav but it's making me nuts that when a user goes from second nav to third one( Future Generations to Israel Overseas) it doesn't work properly. The animation happens twice, sometimes even three times based on how fast you mouse is moved. Moreover, when a nav is open and if you exit the div and come back the animation happens again.

A) Is there a way to fix the issue with going from second to third navigation
B) how do I write a conditional statement so that if a user is with in a section lets say Future Generation and goes outsize the div and comes back it doesn't repeat the close and opening thing again.

CODES at
http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/Hj9my/1/

Note: I cannot use a different jQuery beside 1.2.6 and sorry for the messy HTML code, wanted to make sure it worked on the site, when it works here.

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be missing the js .

Comment: oops sorry! I updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed your accordion , had to lose some of you html as it was a bit confusing . 
updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Hj9my/3/

The code :

```
$(function() {
$(".menu").hover(function() {
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('current').addClass('notcurrent');
    $(this).find('.dropdown').removeClass('notcurrent').addClass('current');
    $('.notcurrent').slideUp();
    $('.current').slideDown();

}, function() {

});
});
```